# Does "left and right" sound unnatural?

Tags: phrase-usage

When referring to the lateral directions, my language expresses them as "**left and right**", for example, as follows:

> Make sure you look **left and right** before crossing the street.

As far as I know, English expresses them as "**right and left**", so I am always confused when writing English.

How much the expression "**left and right**" sound unnatural? Is it unacceptable in formal documents?

Comment: Because we drive on the left in the UK, we're more likely to say [*look **left and right** before crossing*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22look+left+and+right+before+crossing%22) (the *last* side you look is the one most likely to contain a car about to hit you as soon as you step off the pavement, so the instruction is often given as *look right then left, **then right again***). But even though Brits are hopelessly outnumbered by Americans on Google Books, our version comes out way on top there. I can't imagine why.

Comment: The American expression is *look both ways*.

Comment: Sometimes people will also say "look **to the** left and right," as in: _Any time you come to a place where people may cross or enter your path or a line of traffic meets another, you should look to the left and right sides of your vehicle to make sure no one is coming._ (Source: 2017 California Driver Handbook, which shows that the wording may not be driver-side dependent, as @FumbleFingers hypothesized.)

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+left+and+right%2Con+the+right+and+left%2Cto+the+right+and+left%2Cto+the+left+and+right&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) is a really interesting ngram on this

Comment: @J.R.: I find it interesting that there's no discernible difference between US/UK corpuses for your search strings, apart from the fact that the UK charts are more jagged (because there are less hits to smooth things out?). But presumably our UK "Green Cross Code" (highway safety advice) isn't a very significant context in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: ...anyway, I think this one is like ***cats and dogs*** (which I mistakenly thought might be more common overall just because it's always that sequence in the context of heavy rainfall). As opposed to ***coach and horses***, which almost *always* comes in that sequence, whether it's a figurative usage or not.

Comment: @Fumble - Ngrams only lets us input five words, so I couldn't use "Look to the left and right". There are plenty of contexts that may be getting hits here – church choirs ***sway*** to the left and right, ice hockey players **move the puck** to the right and left as they skate down the ice, etc. What I thought was most interesting is that during the 1980s, it didn't seem to matter if you said "left and right" or "right and left". Back up to the start date to 1920 and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound unnatural at all. You can always put the directions in either order. I would never think that "right and left" sounds more natural than "left and right."

Comment: Her looked her **down and up**, and said she seemed to be no worse for the fall?